# What's best practice for submitting passwords over http in iOS?

Tags: ios, http, passwords

Currently, while I've been prototyping the app, I've been doing the following where I hardcode the url login string and submit the login info to that string using sendSynchronousRequest. Is this best practice? I suspect that I should be doing something with keychain for the url and something to safeguard the password.

Edit: Is setting up ssl sufficient?

```
NSString *url = @"http://host/login";
NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@", email, password];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSError        *error = nil;
NSURLResponse  *response = nil;
NSData *tryResponse = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response  error:&error];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the app's point of view that mechanism is just fine.

But sending passwords over http is NEVER secure. You'll need an encryption layer like SSL. So with use of SSL i don't see any issues. (I'm using similar mechanisms in my app, but over SSL and i'm using the async api).

However, it's the server who determines what kind of authentication it accepts and what not. It makes no sense to send the password over https if the server only accepts http.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you should look into WSSE authentication, where you send encrypted user authentication data.
Also, its not good practice to send synchronous request, because your are blocking entire app while sending request. Best practice is to use asynchronous calls on different than main UI thread. I strongly recommend AFNetworking library, as its simple to use, incorporates multithreading and works like charm! https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: Nothing is wrong with using synchronous requests, as long as they are executed in a background thread, which is basically the same as starting an async request from the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for the AF cite. That's useful.